# Django og graph tags issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
  <meta property="og:url" content="{% block ogurl %}{% url 'post:Homepage' %}{% endblock %}" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="{% block ogimage %}{% static 'img/brand/logo.png' %}{% endblock %}" />
```

Result;

```
  <meta property="og:url" content="/" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="/static/img/brand/logo.png" />
```

What I want;

```
  <meta property="og:url" content="sitename.com" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="sitename.com/static/img/brand/logo.png" />
```

Where i did mistake, can you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just [how url works](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

> Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name)
>   matching a given view and optional parameters.

`sitename.com` is redundant for the purpose of `url`

If you want to force that, you can construct the sitename yourself using `{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}`

```
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{% block ogurl %}{% url 'post:Homepage' %}{% endblock %}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{% block ogimage %}{% static 'img/brand/logo.png' %}{% endblock %}" />
```